# Loading Desktop after autostart

Tags: boot

I'm running a python app on boot using:

```
@/usr/bin/python /home/pi/Desktop/file.py
```

that I added to:

*~/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart*

It works great. However when I end the python script the Desktop doesn't load. I don't think there is an infinite loop or something like that cause I use:

```
os.system('killall python')
```

to close the script.

I'm just left with a black screen..

Many thanks :)

Comment: Why do you need to use `killall python`?

Comment: My script is a python app done with Kivy, to stop the execution and leave the app I use a button that calls the "killall python". Also I have a couple processes that gets killed as well

Answer (score 1):

Answer was to add:

```
@startlxde
```

to the autostart file. My autostart file was containing just the python launch command and so after executing the app it wasn't doing anything else.